# Use FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle version 6.0 with Symfony 3.4?

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch

I know a lot of php developers use **FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle** for integration with ElasticSearch, last version ( 6.0 ) supports ElasticSearch 7.*, but require a version of Symfony 4.*. 
For many companies with a lot of codes in projects very hard to move to new version of Symfony. Maybe anyone knows how to use the last version of **FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle** with Symfony 3.4?

Comment: You just can't as it won't be supported from latest version of the bundle.

Comment: @DonCallisto I know about the new version of the bundle is not supported Symfony 3.4, but I think not only me has a problem with not able to update Symfony to version 4*

Comment: OSS just can't address issues for single users. They moved to 4.* and 5.* in order to provide support only for two major versions at a time (and that's sounds reasonable). If you (or others) can't move from symfony 3.4, you just can't use version 6 of the bundle.
BTW remember that moving fron symfony 3.4 to symfony 4 should require only a little work as 4 (and more in general <n>) is 3.4 (and more in general <n-1>.4) with all deprecations removed.